# /dev/ttyS0 doesn't give back prompt after mount

Tags: kernel, tty, serial-port, serial-console

I created a file system and after the mount command i don't get back the prompt in serial port.
I connected to the system also via SSH and i see the mount has been finished.
the serial port continue to print the kernel messages.
when i echo (no matter what) to the serial port (`echo 1 > /dev/ttyS0`) the prompt is backed until the next mount.
How can i check what hold the serial port?
How can i check if there is any process that hold it?
these are the kernel command line arguments relate to ttyS0

```
 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 consoleblank=0 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200  kgdboc=kdb,ttyS0 dyndbg=2+pf
```

Comment: `sudo lsof /dev/ttyS0`,

Comment: the agetty process is hold the ttyS0
i killed the process and it released but i happens each time .
how can i check why the agetty is stuck?
why echo into ttyS0 release it?

Comment: `agetty` is the serial terminal handler, and is the default way the system starts up. Read `man agetty agetty.conf` and look for `/etc/default/agetty*`.